# Sql Range Groups Start and End Id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that I want to break into 'chunks' of size 200 and return the start id and end id of each 'chunk'.

Example:

```
select t.id
from t
where t.x = y --this predicate will cause the ids to not be sequential
```

If the example was the query I'm trying to break into 'chunks' I'd want to return:

(1st ID, 200th ID), (201st ID, 400th ID)...(start of final range ID, end of range ID)

Edit: For the final range, if it is not a full 200 rows it should still supply the final id in the query.

Is there a way to do this with just SQL or will I have to resort to application processing and/or multiple queries similar to a pagination implementation?

If there is a way to do this in SQL please supply an example.

Comment: [OFFSET ... FETCH ...](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

Comment: @lad2025 I've never used those keywords. Thank you I'll see what I can come up with and update my question if still having problems.

Comment: I still not clear if you want a list of numbers `begin; end; being; end;`  or pairs `(begin,end)` or the list of `ids` inside a range `(begin,end)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The second option. Pairs, (begin, end), (begin, end), etc..

Comment: So for example `(3,557)` will have 200 items because ids arent consecutives?

Comment: Yes, the predicate will cause the IDs to not be consecutive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, I think the easiest way is to use `row_number()`:

```
select id
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
      where t.x = y
     ) t
where (seqnum % 200) in (0, 1);
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments:

```
select min(id) as startid, max(id) as endid
from (select t.*,
             floor((row_number() over (order by id) - 1) / 200) as grp
      from t
      where t.x = y
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: Very close to what I'm looking for and would work if I wrote some logic in my application to interpret these results. An ideal solution would give the same results as yours but each row would have (start, end). Also, if the final range isn't a full 200 it should supply the last id in my query; I wasn't explicit in defining that in my OP.

Comment: just add `OR seqnum = (SELECT count(*) FROM table)` to include the last ID.

Comment: That last edit gives the exact results I need. Thanks. Testing for efficiency vs. other answer before accepting either.

Comment: Both answers seemed to perform equally well. I prefer this one though. Thank both of you -- these answers have taught me quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

`L` for Left and `R` for Right

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
          t.id,
          row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
    FROM Table t
    WHERE t.x = y
)
SELECT L.id as start_id, COALESCE(R.id, (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM cte) ) as end_id
FROM cte L
LEFT JOIN cte R
      ON L.seqnum = R.seqnum - 199
WHERE  L.seqnum % 200 = 1
```

<kbd>**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7d70e/7)**</kbd>
filtering only even number and block of 4.

See how `R.seqnum - 199` for a block of size 200

Comment: Having a hard time getting this to work. Getting, 'syntax error at or near "SELECT" referring to ... COALESC(R.id, SELECT MAX(id) FROM ...

Comment: give a sec, i will prepare a sqlfiddle

Comment: I misspell `COALESCE` I also include a sample with smaller data.

Comment: Check help here, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html That is to solve the last null.

Comment: Maybe it is my version of postgres or pgadmin but only way I could get this to work was - COALESCE(R.id, (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM cte) )

Comment: Yes,You are right, i fix it on the sqlfiddle and didnt update the answer.